# Android ResultReceiver how to get location

Tags: android, location, cllocationmanager

I have an location service and activity. i am starting service for get result

by calling "Result Receiver". i get a proper result but i want to get latitude and longitude from service but it return Location mLastLocation null

can somebody help to how to get location from service by calling resultReceiver

Answer (score 1):

What about to get `Latitude` and `Longitude` from **Location**  like below?

```
Location mLastLocation;
Double lat =mLastLocation.getLatitude();
Double longi = mLastLocation.getLongitude()
```

Send location from **Service**

```
 locationBroadcast.putExtra("location", location);
```

get in **Activity**

```
 Location location = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(""location"");
```